# uWSGI: What is the fix for "you have enabled harakiri without post buffering"?

Tags: uwsgi

What configuration setting in a vassal ini for uWSGI would correct this problem?

`*** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be rejected on post-unbuffered webservers ***`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The option is (sorry i know it could look sarcastic but i am not) --post-buffering, but before setting it be sure you have a post-unbuffered webserver as your proxy (like apache). If not you can ignore that message.

If you're using Nginx with either `proxy_pass` or `uwsgi_pass` and haven't explicitly set either `proxy_request_buffering off` or `uwsgi_request_buffering off` respectively, you can safely ignore this warning, since request buffering is on by default since version 1.7.11. See the documentation for [proxy_buffering](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_request_buffering) and [uwsgi_request_buffering](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_request_buffering).

Comment: Do you know if post-buffering should be set for uwsgi running on heroku? Its unclear if the type of buffering they do qualifies as a buffered webserver or if uwsgi would benefit from enabling --post-buffering  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#request-buffering

Comment: Unbuffered request body for uWSGI in Nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_request_buffering